# System Check Engine

Tags: linux, python, rules-engine

I'm looking for a python engine that I can be used to run sophisticated system checks (checking installed software, version of a library, etc.). I'm looking for an engine with the following abilities:

- Checks Bundles: Ability to bundle up checks, i.e. System Checks A, B and C should run sequentially part of a bundle.
- Dependencies: Ability to specify dependencies between Checks and Bundles.
- Multi-threaded Checks: this would be a plus.

There are few rule engines in python:

- pyDatalog
- Pyke
- PyCLIPS
- durable_rules
- Intellect
- business-rules
- PyKnow

Maybe I can re-purpose one of them for this task. I am looking to see if there's any fit for purpose option that fits my needs, or a good recommendation from the above list.